# How To Display Number of People Who Have Me In Google+ Circles?

Tags: google-plus

I have a website that displays the number of Twitter followers, Facebook fans, and LinkedIn connections on each individual account of mine. My problem is with Google+ – I can't seem to find in their API how I can retrieve this information. I want to retrieve/display the number of people who have me on their circles. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: seems it is impossible at the moment

Comment: Yes, I've been stuck with this for a while now. I think it's impossible at the moment too. I was just hoping someone else here might have figured out a workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to show the number of followers you have on Google+ is to use the badge: https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/

The API currently only lets you call people.list() to show the number of people you are following.